# TreeView Binding List<String>

Tags: treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I can't seem to figure out how to get the TreeView to display a List
I checked SO, but can't sem to find the same scenario the leafs always seem to be objects and not simple strings.
I can't figure out the correct combination of HierarchicalDataTemplate and DataTemplate to get it to work. Using the following Object. The binding happens I just only see the first level and not the leaves.

```
    public class Trunk
    {
    public Trunk(string tn)
    {
        TrunkName = tn;
        Branches = new List<Branch>();
    }
    public List<Branch> Branches { get; set; }

    public string TrunkName { get; set; }
}
public class Branch
{
    public Branch(string bn)
    {
        BranchName = bn;
        Leaves = new List<string>();
    }
    public List<string> Leaves { get; set; }

    public string BranchName { get; set; }

}



Tree = new Trunk("Root")
    {
        Branches =
            {
                new Branch("Branch1"){Leaves = {"Leaf1","Leaf2"}},
                new Branch("Branch2"){Leaves = {"Leaf3","Leaf4"}}
            }

    };
```

And the following Template

```
 <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Trees}" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding Branches}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TrunkName}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BranchName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

---

EDIT:
Of course after spending days trying to figure out what wasn't clicking. I figured it out after posting for help.
PS the TreeView ItemsSource is set from the ViewModel bound to the Window DataContext.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Trees}" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding Branches}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TrunkName}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate >
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Leaves}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BranchName}"/>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```